# How to do memory efficient 2D convolution on large arrays

Tags: scipy, numerical-methods, convolution

I have a problem where I need to convolve one very large 2D array (a file on disk) with a smaller array that fits in memory.  `scipy.signal.fftconvolve` is great when the arrays fit in memory but doesn't help when they don't.  Is there any other reasonable approach besides looping over all the points in each array to calculate the convolution manually?  I'm not good with the math, but I'm wondering if the `fftconvolve` could be split into parts and recombined with a little bit of overlap?  Something else?

Comment: what is your "file on disk"?

Comment: File on disk is a GeoTIFF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you two different approaches (although I won't risk providing some example code, hope you won't mind figuring it out):

1) Use [`numpy.memmap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html); "*Memory-mapped files are used for accessing small segments of large files on disk, without reading the entire file into memory. (...) The memmap object can be used anywhere an ndarray is accepted.*"

2) Split the large array into tiles, perform a convolution with `mode='full'`, and superimpose the results. For each tile, you'll get a "border" around the tile, with the same width of your convolution kernel.

It is possible to combine both approaches (for example, read the tiles from a memmapped file, and superimpose the results in another memmapped file which is the result).

Comment: Fantastic!  This worked out great, the overlap slicing was a little tricky but boy howdy does it haul.  About 40s for a 200x200 kernel over a 10000x10000 array that used to MemoryError.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nice to know that this works! I have actually never worked with memmaps, only knew the concept... Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Rich a 10000x10000 geotiff, did you end up manually making a few slices using the memmapped numpy array? I was expecting a size in the millions by millions (thus a wee bit over-engineered)!  Posting a snippet of code on your question could be helpful for somebody in the future.

Comment: @Rich by the way, did you try to apply `fftconvolve` _directly_ on the full memmap array? I have implemented convolution in C#, and the algorithm itself does not increase in memory usage as the base array increase (it depends, yes, on the kernel size). So I believe it should be possible to use memmap only, without the need to tile/split the big array...

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I wasn't clear.  I didn't use the memory mapped arrays at all. I've tried them in the past, but on a 32 bit machine they're still limited to the size of the address space, and they add to the heap so you can't have more than one 2^32 length memory mapped array.  Instead I iterated by small blocks and did the 'full' `fftconvolve` on each one, carefully adding the result back to the existing array.  It's slick.

Comment: Nice to know. If you mind taking a look at the other answer's discussion, you can use `mode=same` and avoid the "border" around each block, thus directly assigning the result to each section without having to sum anything. It should be marginally faster (and probably easier to code).

Answer (score 1):

Futhering heltonbiker's response, getting it done quickly will be important. As will be the re-assembly of your 'tiles'.  If you cannot load your big array into memory then you'll need to load it as a memmapped file...but to have it as a memmapped file you need to first create one.

Here's a rough pseudo code.

```
#you need to know how big your data matrix is

#todo: assign nrows and ncols based on your data.

fp = np.memmap('your_new_memmap_filename.dat', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(nrows, ncols))#create file with appropriate dimensions

data = open('yourdatafile.txt', 'r')
i = 0
for line in data:
    arr = map(float, line.strip().split(','))   #comma delimited? header row?
    fp[i, :] = arr
    i += 1

del fp  #see documentation...del will flush the output and close the file.
```

now to process..can continue or new script

```
convolve_matrix = somenumpyarray
fp_result = np.memmap('your_results_memmap_filename.dat', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(nrows, ncols))

#open big file read only
fp = np.memmap('your_new_memmap_filename.dat', dtype='float32', mode='r', shape=(nrows, ncols))

chunksize = 10000 #?
for i in range(int(nrows/chunksize) - 1):  #don't forget the remainder at the end
    chunk = fp[i * chunksize: (i + 1) * chunksize, :]
    res = fftconvolve(chunk, convolve_matrix)
    fp_result[i * chunksize: (i + 1) * chunksize, :] = res

#deal with remainder

del fp_result
del fp
```

note that this pseudo code does not overlap and you need to fill in some gaps. Also, once you get your tiling working, make sure you use Joblib and process the tiles in parallel. https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html
Sorry I can't give more code, I have a 2-d tiler/reassembler I made for gis but it's not on this computer. It may not even help much because your tiler will not return actual tiles but lists of slices, possibly several lists of where to grab the slice(on big array), where to put it in the results(big result array) and where to slice the result(the convove result of the slice grabbed from big array) of the slice...iterate through the lists of slices and the processing will be easy.  But making your slice function will be tricky.

```
for source_slice, result_slice, mini_slice in zip(source_slice, result_slice, mini_slice):
    matrix2convolve = big_fp[source_slice[0]:source_slice[1], :]
    convolve_result = fftconvolve(matrix2convolve, convolve_matrix)
    big_result_fp[result_slice[0]:result_slice[1], :] = convolve_result[mini_slice[0]:mini_slice[1], :]
```

Comment: Your last line contains a gotcha: since every convolution will produce a "border", you cannot simply assign the result, but instead you should _add_ it (thus using `+=` operator instead of `=`). OR you can assign only the convolution core (which, by the way, should be faster, easier and provide identical results). But then you need to include the argument `fftconvolve(mode='same')`.

Comment: @heltonbiker : yes, you're correct that there are a few ways to treat borders.  Likely, because the 'source_slices' will have overlap with each other(so only a slice within that particular convolution result will be taken), I would use mode='same' as you point out. The slicing numbers could be all calculated in the slicing function ahead of the actual convolving and reassembly so it could accommodate any mode. I suppose the overlap would be half the height of the sliding window matrix along with using mode='same' would be pretty efficient. A very good thing to point out!

Answer (score -1):

It sounds naive, but it's 100% true, if you move the results pixel.

Convolution as it is typically done is wrong. The actual operation requires no memory at all. You can simply read through the file, perform the convolution, and write it back into that same spot.

The flaw in the algorithm as it is performed is that it demands that we have a center pixel. If you rather place the results pixel in the upper left hand corner, perform the convolution. You can simply read through the convolution as a scanline operation. As none of the pixels down or to the right have been changed by this operation, your result is correct.

Once this utterly arbitrary and pointless dependency on previous pixels is broken, you can do cool things like combine convolutions kernels and perform the operation within the same memory footprint (or file) that it's currently being read from.
http://godsnotwheregodsnot.blogspot.com/2015/02/combining-convolution-kernels.html

See the source here http://pastebin.com/bk0A2Z5D

The reason for having the pixels in the center is that they don't sort of move. But, it's not worth it. You really can move them back into the right spot within the same memory if you were dead set on having equal lines of garbage around the result. In fact, if you performed the next convolution with a result in the lower right, and iterated over the array backwards, you'd end up with the results back where they more or less started or with kernel of:

```
0,0
0,1
```

In short, the only reason for your problem is that somebody some time ago decided that there should be a center pixel. When you drop that idiotic idea you always know where the results pixel is, you can do fun operations like precompile convolution matricies, thereby performing all convolutions at once with combined kernels and, for you, perform the operation purely by reading from disk. Just think, you could be the first person to have a blurred copy of that NASA image of the Andromeda Galaxy.

If anybody knows the history of who first made this boondoggle of a decision to have a center pixel, I'd kind of like to know. Because without it, convolution is just a pixel by pixel scanline operation.